# Color primaries, Matrix coefficients and Transfer charcteristics

Tags: video, rgb, yuv, hdr

I'm currently working on a software that performs video processing and I've been looking at handling HDR content.
I'm currently still learning about this topic and I've been looking into the conversion from HDR content to SDR content. While doing so, I've been stumbling upon the following terminology when dealing with color conversion:

- Matrix coefficients
- Colour primarties
- Transfer characteristics and transfer functions

I'm pretty new to this and my knowledge is limited. I'd like to know if anyone could point me to a proper resource (book or online doc) that would cover the basics about the way a YUV image is described and converted to RGB. I'm only finding bits and pieces of information online but I'm struggling to get the full picture.

I'm not sure if my request is clear enough, please let me know if you need extra information.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question **exactly** because converting pixel format from YUV to RGB is a different thing to H264 video codec properties (like Matrix Coeffecients, Color Primaries, etc). Those H264 properties are for the MPEG video decoder to worry about. So... **(1)** Are you making a video processor or are you writing an H264 decoder? **(2)** Do you have a YUV image that needs converting to RGB, and what's not working?

Comment: ITU-T H.273 is the reference. And wikipedia, that is nowadays fully correct in YCbCr article. Also this is enough to get overview. https://res18h39.netlify.app/color As for how the 2 values (Matrix coefficients) were derived from white point and primaries see SMPTE RP 177. As for Colour primaries see color managment and Little-CMS. As for Transfer characteristics just consider HDR transfers, PQ and HLG. Last BT.1886 is the EOTF of BT.709 OETF and is not inverse.